# Linq to SQL - "This member is defined more than once" error

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have the following linq code...

```
CMSDataContext dc = new CMSDataContext();

var q = from u in dc.CMSUsers 
        join d in dc.tblDistricts
          on u.DistrictCode equals d.District into orders
        select u;
```

District shows this error:
Ambiguity between 'tblDistrict.District' and 'tblDistrict.District'

Any ideas?

EDIT:

It turns out that I had the same table in two different dbml files.  Apparently, I cannot do this.  I will have to end up joining a table from one dbml file with another table from a different dbml file.  If anyone can enlighten me on how to do this, I will deem it as an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: LOL, thats a real daft message!

Comment: tell me about it! There must be something wrong with my dbml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a FK releationship between two tables, LINQ-to-SQl will automatically create a property for it.

For example, if you Order object has a CustomerID which is a Foriegn key to the Customers table, Order will automatically have a Customer property.  If you already have a Customer property, there will be a conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I had he same problem. The solution was to **delete** `.dbml` file from the *solution explorer*.